# download video with python webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, video

Is it possible to download a video with `controlslist="nodownload"` and if so how? There is a poster tag and a src tag with urls, but when I tried to open them it only said Bad URL hash.

the whole thing looks like this: `<video controlslist="nodownload" loop="" poster="https://scontent-fra3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t39.35426-6/306972082_627455715702176_816739884095398058_n.jpg?_nc_cat=106&amp;ccb=1-7&amp;_nc_sid=cf96c8&amp;_nc_ohc=gGkqXkxok9sAX-lD2Df&amp;_nc_ht=scontent-fra3-1.xx&amp;oh=00_AfAwpoDJdXRX_30nbuDBub38X9EcpUWJnI4yRPZ2PI1WUA&amp;oe=63D59017" src="https://video-fra3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t42.1790-2/307608880_755324925546967_7278828413698270618_n.?_nc_cat=106&amp;ccb=1-7&amp;_nc_sid=cf96c8&amp;_nc_ohc=2s1fEESN7NUAX_El4Hb&amp;_nc_oc=AQmgHTnQH8pGCmL7kHQnvHKKzkDFJc-6kTQazbteeA1cA21gUhBHplAVKoQmgAfQa2n1lKhOdkZlAXTbObUQycEp&amp;_nc_ht=video-fra3-1.xx&amp;oh=00_AfAOYW5RS8PEp52dlofPE3OtHjgd2SM0dxvk-dhnBIK8BQ&amp;oe=63D18E33" width="100%" height="175"></video>`

any help is appreciated <3

Comment: Can you post the page that you're trying to scrape?

Answer (score 0):

- You can fix the *"Bad URL hash"* by replacing every `&amp;` with `;`. 
  Use **String** functions in your programming language to do this.
- Fixing that above issue brings a new error about an expired/invalid signature. This means the URL changes slightly after some hours.
   **Solution:** Is that you need to always **first** extract the latest version of the link, then **secondly** you attempt to do a file save. If you're lucky, you won't need a step three.